# How does @staticmethod and @classmethod act on the variable in python?

Tags: python, oop, static-methods, class-method

I wrote a simple program.

```
class Sample:

    num =45

    def __init__(self):
        print('Inside constructor')

    @classmethod
    def modifyUsingClassMethod(cls):
        cls.num = cls.num + 45

    @staticmethod
    def modifyUsingStaticMethod():
        Sample.num = Sample.num+5

s1 = Sample()
s2 = Sample()

s1.modifyUsingClassMethod()
print(s1.num, s2.num)

s1.num = s1.num + 5
print(s1.num)

s1.modifyUsingClassMethod()
print(s1.num, s2.num)

s1.modifyUsingStaticMethod()
print(s1.num, s2.num)
```

**Output:**

```
Inside constructor
Inside constructor
90 90
95
95 135
95 140
```

Can anyone explain how and why the `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod` are acting on the variable 'num'?. Why does the output shows `95,135` even after I changed the value of num using s1 instance using `modifyUsingClassMethod()` and why not it is updating in both cases using `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod`?

I guess when I am referring to the variable `num` using class object then python is treating the variable `num` as an instance variable but when I change the variable `num` using Class name then the value is not updating in the `s1` but in `s2`. I am highly confused how `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` works.

Comment: I think you are guesing it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your class-method and your static-method only ever change the class-level variable. The issue is that you've *shadowed* your class-variable `num` inside your instance variable, `s1`, when you did this:

```
s1.num = s1.num + 5
```

This creates an instance variable that shadows the class variable in the instances namespace. When you access an object, the instance's namespace will be checked, if an attribute with that name isn't found, it will try the classes name-space, and then it will check the namespaces of all the classes in the method-resultion-order: the MRO (this *is* inheritance).

So consider your example:

```
In [1]: class Sample:
   ...:     num =45
   ...:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         print('Inside constructor')
   ...:
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def modifyUsingClassMethod(cls):
   ...:         cls.num = cls.num + 45
   ...:
   ...:     @staticmethod
   ...:     def modifyUsingStaticMethod():
   ...:         Sample.num = Sample.num+5
   ...:

In [2]: s1 = Sample()
   ...: s2 = Sample()
   ...:
   ...: s1.modifyUsingClassMethod()
   ...: print(s1.num,s2.num)
   ...:
   ...: s1.num = s1.num + 5
   ...: print(s1.num)
   ...:
   ...: s1.modifyUsingClassMethod()
   ...: print(s1.num,s2.num)
   ...:
   ...: s1.modifyUsingStaticMethod()
   ...: print(s1.num,s2.num)
   ...:
Inside constructor
Inside constructor
90 90
95
95 135
95 140
```

And now look at the objects:

```
In [4]: vars(Sample)
Out[4]:
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Sample' objects>,
              '__doc__': None,
              '__init__': <function __main__.Sample.__init__>,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Sample' objects>,
              'modifyUsingClassMethod': <classmethod at 0x107c3fe48>,
              'modifyUsingStaticMethod': <staticmethod at 0x107c3ff98>,
              'num': 140})

In [5]: vars(s1)
Out[5]: {'num': 95}

In [6]: vars(s2)
Out[6]: {}
```

You can clearly see the namespace of `s1` has `num` in it, shadowing the one in the namespace of `Sample`.

Note what happens when we delete `num` from the instances name-space:

```
In [11]: del s1.num

In [12]: s1.num
Out[12]: 140
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation:

```
s1.num = s1.num + 5
```

causes s1 to contain a local copy of `.num`.  If you remove that from your test code, you will see that without that, the properties continue to track themselves over time.